# How to download only one jar with pom.xml?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I want to use a project called projectA that I have in a maven repository as dependency of a projectB.

The mvn deploy of projectA is successful (I can see in the repository the projectA-0.0.1-20190902.072951-1.jar, projectA-0.0.1-20190902.072951-1.pom and maven-metadata.xml files), but when I specify the dependency in the pom.xml file of projectB, the project works but it downloads two JARs of projectA from the repository:

```
- projectA-0.0.1-20190902.072951-1.jar
- projectA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and the same issue for every file downloaded by the dependency to this project.
```

I think that only one JAR is necessary, and I don't know what I need to put maybe in settings.xml or in the pom.xml file of any project to get only one JAR when the dependency is downloaded.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Could you add the exact logging of part you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

In the past it was possible to tell Maven to deploy [Non-unique Snapshot Deployments](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-Non-uniqueSnapshotDeployments) but in Maven 3

> ... snapshot artifacts will always be deployed using a timestamped version

So:

- the files with the timestamps are the one you have deployed to your remote repo (`mvn deploy ...`) and then downloaded from there as dependencies
- the ones with `-SNAPSHOT` are the result of the local builds (`install` goal)

If your concern is download traffic - that is not an issue. The `-SNAPSHOT` ones are not downloaded.

If your concern is disk space then you can have a cron job or use something like [Build Helper Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/remove-project-artifact-mojo.html) to remove old version artifacts from the local repository.

Comment: But when the project downloads the dependency of the remote project, I look for the JAR and I see that two jars have been downloaded, shouldn't only one be downloaded? They are not the same but with different name? Thank you so much!

Comment: Try this. Remove the whole folder for project A from local repo. Build and deploy project A. You should now have a `-SNAPSHOT` jar in your local repo. Remove the whole folder for project A from local repo again. Build project B (which has dependency on A). You should now only have a timestamp version of the project A in your local repo.

Comment: But any reason about why the jar is downloaded two times one with suffix SNAPSHOT and other with suffix timestamp?

Should it be downloaded one or the other? Is one more important than the other or are they the same but with a different name?

Comment: Did you try the steps from the previous message? Doesn't it work as I described?